# Vue component property undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, pug

I'm pretty new to Vue.  I have an AJAX request that occurs at an interval and updates an object that is used in my Pug template.  When the data is referenced alone with the double curly brackets it shows up fine, but when it's used in something like a for each loop it is undefined and breaks the component.

```
<template lang="pug">
.mycomponent
  p {{ data }}  <- this reference to data works fine
  if data != undefined <- this reference to data is undefined
    each val, index in data
      li= val + ': ' + index
</template>
```

To set data, I'm doing this:

```
mounted () {
  setInterval(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/info')
      .catch((error) => console.log(error.request))
      .then(response => {
        this.data = response.data
      })
  },
  3000)
},
```

Why is data undefined?

Answer (score 1):

You can do :

```
<template lang="pug">
.mycomponent
  p {{ data }}
  ul(v-if="data !== undefined")
    li(v-for="(val, index) in data") {{ val }} : {{ index }}
</template>
```